# Parameterized Query creating Many Plans

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqlperformance, parameterized-query

I have some Queries those are parameterized they are still creating new execution plan each time, I am using SQL Server 2016

Queries are like :

```
(@P1 varchar(1043),@P2 varchar(6))
UPDATE table 
SET FILEDATA=@P1 
WHERE FILEID=@P2
```

This query is not using the already generated execution plan from the cache rather it is creating a new plan each time while execution

[This image shows the plancount an individual query is creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmbH.png)

Comment: (1) How did you validate that they are not using the same plan? (2) How frequently does the data in that table change? If it changes too frequently, the statistics might be getting invalidated, and that would force the engine to regenerate the execution plan. (3) Do you have any repetitive jobs that reset the stats or rebuild the indexes on that table? (4) Did you verify that the plan cache is not full?

Comment: 1) I have run one script to get the count of plans
2) very frequent(may I know how to validate statistics )
3)No Such Jobs 
4) Yes I have Verified it is not full

Comment: (1) But have you actually verified that there are duplicate plans for that query? (2) If the data is changing very frequently - SQL server has to update the execution plan based on new stats - which is a good thing. Check the last creation time for stats on the table, and compare that with the date on execution plan to verify.

Comment: Parameter sniffing...https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: As suggested, you first need to determine if you have several plans for the same query (and *how* many). Note that data types matters, as does connection settings (like ARTIHABORT) - such things makes SQL Server see different queries.

Comment: I have added one image as a snapshot of my queries and in that "plancount" is the number of plans created by the individual query, as it can be seen that same queries are creating 11 execution plans each time

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me in the past and the following fixed it for me:

- Make sure all this code is in a stored procedure.  Even with params a stored procedure is much more likely to reuse the same plan.
- I won't repeat what Nisarg Shah said in the comments as it looks like you have addressed those, but those are all very valid things to check.
- This may sound weird but fully qualify the code as much as possible.  In my experience it's much more likely to find the existing plan if it's having problems doing so if it's crafted like this:

  ```
  (@P1 varchar(1043),@P2 varchar(6))
  UPDATE database.dbo.table 
  SET database.dbo.table.FILEDATA=@P1 
  WHERE database.dbo.FILEID=@P2
  ```

Normally I don't write my queries like that as they seem a little harder to read, but it's worked for me in the past when I get piles of plans.

Comment: Please see I have added one image in my question that may help to answer this question in depth because fully qualified queries are not helping me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah it looks like your `@P1` is varying in size enough to trigger making a new plan.  Perhaps that's for the best?  If you like to force it to use the same plan, here is a a good idea on the way to do it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130413/fixed-query-plan-for-a-stored-procedure  If that doesn't work, https://dba.stackexchange.com might get you a better answer if you post on there.  Good luck!